# get data from sales order and sales order item in magento

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento php code to get the Customer Name, email, product description, sku code, order number and customer id. However I have been feeling a bit stuck when trying to join the "sales/order" and "sales/order_item" models in order to print out the data through a foreach loop and also get only the now date. This is what I got so far:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('uk');
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','DESC');
foreach ($collection as $c) {
    echo $c->getCustomerName() . "\t" .
    $c->getCustomerEmail() . "\t" .
    $c->getCreatedAt() . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Could you please give me a hand with this?

Thanks a lot,

Nestor

Answer (score 5):

try below code

```html
foreach ($collection as $c) {
 $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($c->getId());
 $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
 foreach($ordered_items as $item){
   echo $item->getItemId(); 
   echo $item->getSku(); -
 }
    echo $c->getCustomerName() . "\t" .
    $c->getCustomerEmail() . "\t" .
    $c->getCreatedAt() . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got your code in my php script. It is working but I need to order the orders by today's date and on the other hand I need to relate it to the 'catalog/product' model so I can get the short description and the product link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151134/get-orders-items-from-last-24-hours-in-magento